# Logging onto work VPN using linux

Tags: vpn, vnc, openvpn, sshfs

I am new to linux. I was using windows for years now ,and my work from home was done by using vnc viewer. I use vnc to log into an linux system. Now I am using a linux system , is there any way i can skip vnc viewer ? I can ping to my work Ip.

I can use screen or other such things, but i thought if there was a way i can mount my work linux system and work on my desktop itselfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several way to connect to a remote Linux machine.

1. Shell access

   You can use ssh: in a local terminal, use `ssh login@host` and you got a remote terminal.
2. Single window access

   Just add `-X` option to ssh to enable X11 Forwarding : like in 1, you'll have a terminal on the remote host, but any graphical application that you launch on your term will be displayed locally. IMHO, this is the best option.
3. Whole desktop access

   You can use a vnc client like `vinegar`.

There is also other protocols but some are really old (xdmcp), and other may be too young (nx).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to mount your work filesystem and you can already ping it, then the easiest thing you can do is the following:

On your work computer (or the appropriate alternative if it's not running Ubuntu), run:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Now, on your client machine, run:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

Then mount the remote filesystem with:

```bsh
sshfs $USER@$WORK_IP:/path/to/directory /path/to/local/mount
```

You will need to enter your work user's password to mount the filesystem, so make sure it is something secure.

[NFS is also an alternative](http://programster.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/ubuntu-set-up-nfs.html) but more advanced in my opinion, hence requires a tutorial.

Comment: I tried mounting using sshfs. It works , but i am not able to compile my code. The wrappers don't work. When i try to compile , it goes to find wrappers in /bin/ of my directory and not the mounted space ?!?!?!

Comment: Yes you will have issues like that as the filesystem will only be mounted at the specified path, so any code that uses an absolute path (e.g. /bin) probably wont work. In situations like that you would either need to just SSH into the remote machine like the accepted answer and actually do everything on the remote machine rather than just accessing its files on your local one. I hope the subtle difference with which computer is actually "doing" the work came across.